# I have a moderate to high correlation and a p-value that is non-significant. Do I still reject the whole hypothesis?

Tags: r, correlation, p-value, pearson-r

I have a correlation of 0.777 but only a p-value of 0.069 (not significant) on my Pearson's test. My sample size was of 54. Should my hypothesis still be rejected even if there is a correlation? Is the non-significant p-value due to sample size?
What can I say about the hypothesis in this case?

Comment: I think something's wrong with the p-value calculation.  For a sample size of 50 an *r* of 0.27 should be a *p*-value of about 0.05.

Comment: See, [real-statistics.com/statistics-tables/pearsons-correlation-table/](https://real-statistics.com/statistics-tables/pearsons-correlation-table/). Just approximately, for df = 52, *r* = 0.77, I get *t* = 8.8, *p* = 8e-12.

Comment: I apologise, I have made a mistake in my question. My sample size was of 6.

Comment: Then, yes, with a sample size of 6, I think you would need an *r* of, say, 0.82 to get a *p*-value less than 0.05.

Comment: @broccolops in statistics, this is what we call a "game changer".

Comment: It sounds like you might like to read the answers at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31 concerning what p-values mean and how to interpret them.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure this question is covered elsewhere on this site.  But basically, for Pearson correlation, there is a relationship between sample size, the correlation coefficient, and the resultant *p*-value.

This relationship can be seen on tables like this one: [real-statistics.com/statistics-tables/pearsons-correlation-table/](https://real-statistics.com/statistics-tables/pearsons-correlation-table/), or can be found in many analysis of experiments textbooks.

For a given *r* value, the *p*-value becomes smaller as the sample size increases.  This is basically a feature of how we do hypothesis testing.

Practically speaking, getting a relatively large *r* value with a small sample size is *suggestive*.  Likely, there is a real correlation, but we have limited evidence against the possibility that this apparent correlation occurred simply by chance.  Likewise, a *p*-value less than 0.10 is suggestive, but certainly not dispositive.

Comment: +1. Worth considering is that, with such a lack of precision in the estimate, there is a real chance that the true correlation is *less than zero*, despite the empirical correlation of $0.777$.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a significance test, you reject, or you fail to reject, the null hypothesis based on the p-value from the significance test.

Your p-value is not significant, therefore you fail to reject the null hypothesis. You have not found evidence that the null hypothesis is false.

You ask "Do I still reject the whole hypothesis?" No. You do not reject any hypotheses because of a non-significant test.